# Cannot convert value of type 'dispatch_queue_t' to expected argument type 'NSOperationQueue'

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, swift2

Came across this error when I trying to do:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
                ........
})
```

Is there a bridge between the c-type-like queue return by "dispatch_get_global_queue" and the object-oriented version NSOperationQueue? Or can we cast from one to another?

How does people deal with it if a queue is created via the c-type function, and later on some function call requires the object-oriented version queue?

Comment: There's no bridge. Create and use an `NSOperationQueue` instead of GCD.

Comment: Ok. I guess that is the way it is. Might need to create multiple queues for different type requirement. It is a bit of inconvenient.